# Remove post featured image

Tags: nodes

I want to remove post featured image from http://bit.ly/XkE8vG.
I have tried a lot by looking in to theme files but couldn't find any way.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the content types page on admin/structure/types, click on "Manage display," and drag the field to the "Hidden" set.

[image]

**For D6**

You can do the same in `node-type/<type>/display`. Click exclude/ make the select box to hidden.

Also you can use this code in node.tpl.php.

```
if ($teaser) { 
  // node is being displayed as a teaser
  // Anything here will show up when the teaser of the post is viewed in your taxonomies or front page
} else { 
  //all other cases
  //Anything here will show up when viewing your post at any other time, e.g. previews
}
```

Comment: Hello M confused, I am using drupal 7, not able to find any thing like this in blog.

Comment: I tried here RAMADA EDMONTON HOTEL> ADMINISTER > CONTENT MANAGEMENT> BLOG ENTRY > DISPLAY FIELDS

Comment: @AjayPatel, you try what i mentioned.

Comment: see the edited post , i have attached image

Comment: Try the same with Bartik theme.

Comment: I couldn't find that theme ...

Comment: @AjayPatel, its in your Drupal by default.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7980/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-nikhil-m)